# Counting self avoiding walks in a strip

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the strip $\{0,1,\ldots n\}\times\{0,1,2\}$ in $\mathbb{N}^2.$ Is a formula known for the total number of self avoiding walks in this strip starting at $(0,0)$ in terms of the parameter $n$?

*Edit:* I mean *all* the walks that take steps of $(\pm 1,0),(0,\pm1)$ as long as they are confined to that strip.

Comment: When you say "walk", do you mean each step is either horizontal or vertical, or could they be diagonal too? And do you mean only walks that are maximal in length (can't take another step), or walks of any length?

Comment: Basically anything related to self-avoiding walk is an open research question, so I doubt it.